Cannot connect to RDS with hostname, only with IP
I've recently joined a new team and I have to connect to a Postgresql DB deployed on AWS RDS.
Everyone in my team manages to access it with their chosen OS, VPN (openVPN or AWSVPN, both work with the exact same config file) and DB tool (DBeaver, PGAdmin, other) and they are using the aws endpoint as the hostname which looks like  appdata-dev.xxxxxxxxxx0f.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
I am working on Windows 11 and using PGAdmin4 and OpenVPN (with the same config file as my colleagues). When I add a new server in PGAdmin and fill in all the details, the connection fails with this message:
details-with-hostname
connection-error-message
However, when I provide the DB IP instead of the endpoint string as a hostname, it connects perfectly:
details-with-IP
This is not specific to PGAdmin, I have also tried with DBeaver and Azure Data studio and I get the same result.
I also have the same result in my backend services which require a connection to this DB (with the hostname and other details provided in my env/config file, it fails when the hostname is the endpoint string but it works when I change it to the IP)
config-file-change
To resolve the issue, I've tried setting the DNS addresses (IPv4) manually on my wifi and VPN settings with 8.8.4.4 / 8.8.8.8 (which was enough of a fix for some of my colleagues on Linux), but it doesn't seem to fix anything for me.
network-dns-setup
My ISP is Virgin media and I have a Hub 5 router, but I don't think that's the issue because I've tried it on other networks (mobile tethering and other wifi), and it still didn't work.
I know for sure that there's nothing wrong at AWS level because all my other colleagues can access it fine and we have the same profile settings and permissions on AWS. The RDS also doesn't have specific whitelisted IP addresses.
The only difference that could potentially be relevant is: out of the people using Windows, I am the only one using Windows 11, my colleagues are on Windows 10 and have no issue to connect to it.
At this point, I don't know where else to look... :(
If anyone has a suggestion, I'd be so grateful!!
Update:
Adding a screenshot here of what happens when I ping/nslookup the hostname:
ping-nslookup-result

Are you connected to a VPN... is it possible that the VPN connection is forcing you to use some specific DNS servers that are unable to resolve this hostname?
You can try setting your VPN client to not override your DNS settings.
You can always use the dig +trace command to query for the hostname which might help narrow it down to being a dns issue or not

If you ping the DNS name, does it display an IP address? (You can ignore the actual ping results.) Does the IP address look like a private IP address within the CIDR of the VPC (eg 10.x.x.x or 172.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x)?

when I ping, it only displays a message saying it couldn't find the host.
I've added a pic for that in the question and I also did a nslookup for that hostname and you can see the result showing it times out. Does that help you @JohnRotenstein ?

Interesting! If you repeat the ping process with a computer that works, I expect that you will see the DNS name resolution working. So, that is the root of your problem. According to Should a non-public RDS instance have a publicly resolvable DNS name? | AWS re:Post, even a private RDS database should have a DNS name that can resolve to an IP address, but it will be a private IP address. You'll need to concentrate on fixing the DNS resolution problem on that machine.

Actually, we've only tried with 1 other computer so far, but that person had the same ping/nslookup response as me (failed) even though they could connect with hostname in DBeaver and in their backend app when running it. So that got us well confused...

Sorry replacing previous comment with an update: Actually, we've tried on 2 other computer so far. One person had the same failed ping/nslookup response as me. Another person had a resolved lookup but a failed ping.

Another update, after troubleshooting further with a colleague, we ended up editing my hosts file located at: windows > system32 > drivers > etc > hosts. In this file we added a line which was like '{IP} {hostname}'. After that, I am able to connect to the RDS using hostname in PGAdmin and also when running backend repos. The nslookup/ping still timeout.  Not a complete fix, I still have the hosts file to keep up to date @JohnRotenstein are the additional updates helpful? does that still look like a DNS issue? thanks in advance!

You're basically telling the computer how to resolve that DNS Name. It's no different to simply entering the IP address instead of the DNS name. This is fine, but the IP address might change if the database is restarted or has failover. The reason it can't be resolved is that the database is set to Publicly Available = No, which means the DNS name can only be resolved within the VPC itself, or if your VPN connection points to the VPC's DNS server. See @MartinW's comments at the top -- it's all about the interaction between the VPN client and the DNS server.

and just to comment on the ping failing even though the DNS resolution works. This is potentially quite normal, if the security group for your database only allows the postgres port and not ICMP traffic then a ping will always fail... Potentially this is a good thing as it means people scanning the internet for open servers have less chance of finding it

thanks for explaining further. that really helps! There is one thing I still don't understand, if the database is set to 'Publicly Available = No' on AWS, how come other team members can get to it without any fixes. We're supposed to all have the same profiles on AWS, but does the VPC interact with profiles? Even though I belong to the same team and have the same accesses, is it possible that I'm missing a VPC setting somewhere?

It possibly goes back to my first comment...
If the DB is not publicly available then that means you must be using a VPN to connect to it.
It's possible that the VPN server is forcing you to use some specific DNS servers that can't resolve the hostname, try setting your vpn client to not use the DNS servers specified by the VPN server.... Or maybe it's the other way round, maybe there are some internal DNS servers that you should be using but your VPN client is configured to ignore them and use your laptops default ones
